# XPath predicates in conditional expressions

Tags: java, xpath

I have the following XML instance:

```
<entities>
    <person>
        James
    </person>
    <legalEntity legalName="ACME">
    </legalEntity>
    <criminalOrganization>
        <organizationName>Mafia</organizationName>
    </criminalOrganization>
</entities>
```

And wish to produce a print-out with the *type* and *name* of each entity.

*type* is simply the element name (`person`, `legalEntity` or `criminalOrganization`), 
*name* is defined differently according to the kind of entity.

So I have the following code:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/entities/(person|legalEntity|criminalOrganization)");
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0 ; i < nodes.getLength() ; i++) {
    Node node = nodes.item(i);
    String nodeName = node.getNodeName();
    XPathExpression exprInner = xpath.compile("text()|@legalName|organizationName/text()");
    String name = (String) exprInner.evaluate(node);
    System.out.printf("node type = %s, name = %s\n", nodeName, name);
}
```

The code produces the output:

```
 node type = person, name = 
         James

 node type = legalEntity, name = ACME
 node type = criminalOrganization, name =
```

So basically, the name of `person` entities is fetched OK (I just have to trim it), the name of `legalEntity` is also fetched properly, but the name of `criminalOrganization` is not.

Upon investigation I discovered that this is due to the fact that the first expression in the XPath `union` structure: `text()|@legalName|organizationName/text()` also evaluates (I suppose to some empty string value) in the case of `criminalOrganization` so it is returned as the evaluated value of the entire union expression (rather than the last component `organizationName/text()`).

My questions are:

1. why does this mixup not happen also in the case of `legalEntity`?
2. how do I include element name predicates in the `union` XPath expression to ensure that each component evaluates only for the intended type. I.e. `text()` for `person` elements, `@legalName` for `legalEntity` elements and `organizationName/text()` for `criminalOrganization` elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion your solution is somehow a little bit strange but you may try to use `self::` .

Try this (not tested):

```
XPathExpression exprInner 
      = xpath.compile("self::person/text()|
                       self::legalEntity/@legalName|
                       self::criminalOrganization/organizationName/text()");
```

Comment: Yeap, that works. Can you elaborate on what is strange and how you would do it differently cause I'm new to XPath and not familiar with the best practices / usual patterns, etc.

Comment: Also, why didn't I see the same mixup in the case of the `legalEntity` element?

Comment: There is no mixup. The `evaluate()` with your expression return a list of nods, the nodes are in document order (not in order of you expression. But the attributes for  `legalEntity  is before any text-node. The `(String) ` force to return only the "text" of the first node.

Comment: I would prefer to have a switch case over the node name of the first evaluate and than select the content depending on the already known node (even if this would be a little more code)